# How would these Rise of the Runelords characters evolve?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, published-adventures, rise-of-the-runelords

I'm running the *Rise of the Runelords* adventure path. Since we are reaching the story's end I'm considering having the PCs meet again…

> Nualia, a CE female aasimar fighter 2/cleric 4 of Lamashtu, and her lover Tsuto, a half-elf rogue 2/monk 2

…except advancing each to about level 16. However, I'm struggling with what their progressions might be. Based on the way these NPCs are described in the adventure what classes and feats make the most sense for N. and T.?

Comment: Even with the edit, the question might get closed, but I'm not particularly familiar with *Runelords*, so maybe someone who's made a detailed examination of the text or played it a couple of times can offer an opinion *that's supported by evidence* on possible progressions of these character? Good luck!

Comment: Though this is opinion-based, there are references from the authors that can make answers objective. Answers can either give their own opinion (which would flag this as opinion-based) or list what the authors intended for those npcs if a GM decides to keep them alive (which might not be obvious for those that haven't checked content outside of the book).

Comment: Yeah, if this  question was either just  asking for the guidance from the adventure on scaling or had some specific goals for the higher level version this would be answerable, but as is it's "whatever anyone thinks is cool" which doesn't work here in our format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not played through *Runelords*, but found a couple of other threads (links if you'd like to take a look, both of these are spoiler-y [thread #1](https://www.reddit.com/r/Pathfinder_RPG/comments/3ohw4e/concerning_nualia_rotrl_spoilers/) [thread #2](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-392867.html)) that pointed to the following paragraph in the Anniversary edition (page 65):

> It’s possible that Nualia escapes death in this adventure—in this case, she makes her way to Magnimar as soon as she can to rejoin her allies there. When the PCs confront the Skinsaw Cult in Chapter Two, they should find evidence that Nualia has visited them recently, but her exact role in the rest of the campaign is left to you. She could end up aiding Lucrecia’s efforts against Turtleback Ferry, become one of Mokmurian’s allies, join forces with the Scribbler, or even make the pilgrimage to Xin-Shalast to pledge her service to Karzoug. You should advance her levels as appropriate to keep her a powerful enemy (three levels or so above the average party level)—consider giving her levels of the divine scion prestige class detailed in Pathfinder Campaign Setting: Inner Sea Magic. She could even complete her transformation into a demon— this ritual is detailed in full on page 45 of Pathfinder Campaign Setting: Book of the Damned II: Lords of Chaos. Nualia as a half-fiend, or even as a succubus, would certainly make an even more dangerous foe than a mere wayward aasimar!

Not finding much mentioned for "T." but that might give you some ideas or starting place for "N.". Having not actually played it, I'm not sure what kind of builds fit their backstories.

Comment: Note that a lot of community members agree that she should be rewritten with warpriest levels, as the class didnt exist back then and is thematically fitting.